# How to retrieve a value via get_option when the option_value is stored in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to determine how to retrieve custom values from wp_options when the values are stored in a single options array.

For example, I've got the following data in wp_options for option_value where option_name = "my_category_fields_option". The i:n value represents the category id of the category that holds the custom "my_title" data]

a:2:{i:10;a:1:{s:8:"my_title";s:48:"Iced Tea: A Great Choice for Cooling Refreshment";}i:20;a:1:{s:8:"my_title";s:30:"Black Tea is Good for the Soul";}}

How would I retrieve the value for "my_title" (which should be "Hello World") when I'm viewing the category archive page for this category?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$term_id = get_query_var('cat'); // the current category ID

$my_fields = get_option('my_category_fields_option');
echo $my_fields[$term_id]['my_title']; // the title corresponding to the current category
```

(assuming you're talking about [Any examples of adding custom fields to the category editor?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6549/any-examples-of-adding-custom-fields-to-the-category-editor/6599#6599))

Answer (score 2):

If you pass an array to the update_option it will automatically serialize it. you can later retrieve them back into an array like this.

```
$tempoptions = get_option("plugin-options");
if (!empty($tempoptions)) {
    foreach ($tempoptions as $key => $option)
        $options[$key] = $option;
}
```

then do something like var_dump (`$options`) this will show you the entire array.

I think they use the maybe_serialize/maybe_unserialize/is_serialized functions from the codex, but I never really looked into it. Just found them now. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize