# Add custom field to Category

Tags: categories

I'd like to add custom fields to a certain category.
A category only has the following fields:

Name:

Slug:

Parent:

Description:

Since I have a TV Series Site, I want to add some more fields, I want something like this, when I create a new category (Category=Series)

Name:

Artist:

Year:

Type:

Genre:

Summary:

Slug:

Parent:

Description:

And so on...

Any help please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any examples of adding custom fields to the category editor?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6549/any-examples-of-adding-custom-fields-to-the-category-editor)

Comment: Here is a cheat sheet I use when doing this. It has the relevant action hooks & filters in one short list.
http://www.charlestonsw.com/adding-custom-fields-to-the-wordpress-category-interface/

Answer (score 27):

I posted an How To about it a week ago http://en.bainternet.info/2011/wordpress-category-extra-fields

hope this helps.

Ohad.

---

### Here are the details of the post:

The first thing we need to do is add the extra fields to the category edit form using the hook edit_category_form_fields and we use a simple function that will print out the extra fields.

```
<?php
//add extra fields to category edit form hook
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'extra_category_fields');

//add extra fields to category edit form callback function
function extra_category_fields( $tag ) {    //check for existing featured ID
    $t_id = $tag->term_id;
    $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
?>
<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_Image_url"><?php _e('Category Image Url'); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Cat_meta[img]" id="Cat_meta[img]" size="3" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $cat_meta['img'] ? $cat_meta['img'] : ''; ?>"><br />
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Image for category: use full url with '); ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="extra1"><?php _e('extra field'); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Cat_meta[extra1]" id="Cat_meta[extra1]" size="25" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $cat_meta['extra1'] ? $cat_meta['extra1'] : ''; ?>"><br />
        <span class="description"><?php _e('extra field'); ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="extra2"><?php _e('extra field'); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="Cat_meta[extra2]" id="Cat_meta[extra2]" size="25" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $cat_meta['extra2'] ? $cat_meta['extra2'] : ''; ?>"><br />
        <span class="description"><?php _e('extra field'); ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="form-field">
<th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="extra3"><?php _e('extra field'); ?></label></th>
<td>
        <textarea name="Cat_meta[extra3]" id="Cat_meta[extra3]" style="width:60%;"><?php echo $cat_meta['extra3'] ? $cat_meta['extra3'] : ''; ?></textarea><br />
        <span class="description"><?php _e('extra field'); ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

As you can see i added 4 new fields and all of them are in an array Cat_meta[key] because that way we only create on row in the options table to save all of the category's extra fields instead of a row for each field.

Next we need to save the extra fields in to the database once a user submits the category edit form and we do that using "edited_category" with a function that will run through each of the submitted fields and insert them to the database using the update_option function, like this:

```
<?php
// save extra category extra fields hook
add_action ( 'edited_category', 'save_extra_category_fileds');

// save extra category extra fields callback function
function save_extra_category_fileds( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['Cat_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $cat_meta = get_option( "category_$t_id");
        $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['Cat_meta']);
            foreach ($cat_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['Cat_meta'][$key])){
                $cat_meta[$key] = $_POST['Cat_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        //save the option array
        update_option( "category_$t_id", $cat_meta );
    }
}
```

From the code above you can see that all of the extra fields we've added are stored in the database's options table with the name 'category_ID' , where ID is the id of the specific category we just edited and that means we can call this data in our plugins or theme files easily using the get_option function.

say for example my category id is 25 then my code will look like

```
<?php $cat_data = get_option('category_25'); ?>
```

As I stated in the beginning, I need to display a different image for each category, so in that case I added these few lines of code to my theme's category.php right after the code that displays the category title:

```
<?php
//first get the current category ID
$cat_id = get_query_var('cat');

//then i get the data from the database
$cat_data = get_option("category_$cat_id");

//and then i just display my category image if it exists
if (isset($cat_data['img'])){
    echo '<div class="category_image"><img src="'.$cat_data['img'].'"></div>';
}
```

Nice and easy and we are all done. The result should look similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Please post the main content of your blog into this answer. Link rot can happen, even on your own blog.

Comment: This was answered at 2011 buddy :)

Comment: Your point being?

Comment: why wake up the dead? feel free to edit the answer if you want.

Comment: If you don't think this answer has any value, it should be deleted... However this question has over 16,000 views. I think it the question remains useful for people, despite its age, and this answer would be improved by including the details from the link in question.

Comment: In fact, the more time that passes, the more pressing it becomes to capture the essence of the answer here, lest it disappear from where it's linked to...

Comment: ...while you guys were busy debating it (a year ago albeit), it took me less than 5 minutes to bring everything over into the answer. It's easy...

Comment: What file are you modifying here?

Answer (score 20):

As of Wordpress 4.4, the [add_term_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta), the [update_term_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_term_meta) and [get_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/) functions have been added. This means that the code as provided by MxmastaMills can be updated to use a far less hacky approach.

Here is my update of it. There is only one field as I wanted to add a custom title, but it'll work the same for all the fields you want to add.

```
function addTitleFieldToCat(){
    $cat_title = get_term_meta($_POST['tag_ID'], '_pagetitle', true);
    ?> 
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_page_title"><?php _e('Category Page Title'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
        <input type="text" name="cat_title" id="cat_title" value="<?php echo $cat_title ?>"><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Title for the Category '); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php

}
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'addTitleFieldToCat');

function saveCategoryFields() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['cat_title'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta($_POST['tag_ID'], '_pagetitle', $_POST['cat_title']);
    }
}
add_action ( 'edited_category', 'saveCategoryFields');
```

Comment: Few things to note: in the `edited_category` hook, `tag_ID` will be in the `$_POST` array, not in the `$_GET`. Also `add_term_meta` will actually add a new entry instead of overriding a possible old one. Use `update_term_meta` instead.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov Could you fix luke-simmons's answer by clicking on edit button? This way everyone can use the best code available, even who does not code very well (designer here!). Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't save the data in the form

Comment: @Dev it does save data, it just don't show it unless you change $_POST to $_GET in second line.

Answer (score 7):

This code works:

```
add_action ( 'category_edit_form_fields', function( $tag ){
    $cat_title = get_term_meta( $tag->term_id, '_pagetitle', true ); ?>
    <tr class='form-field'>
        <th scope='row'><label for='cat_page_title'><?php _e('Category Page Title'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='cat_title' id='cat_title' value='<?php echo $cat_title ?>'>
            <p class='description'><?php _e('Title for the Category '); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr> <?php
});
add_action ( 'edited_category', function( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['cat_title'] ) )
        update_term_meta( $term_id , '_pagetitle', $_POST['cat_title'] );
});
```

Comment: This is less clumsy than the other one and I just verified it with WordPress 5.2.2

Comment: This code worked for me, the other one didn't, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Paul Menard provided an example of how to create and use term meta in his blog...
[***Custom meta for new taxonomies in WordPress 3.0***](http://www.codehooligans.com/2010/07/07/custom-meta-for-new-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/).

There's no example of creating the DB table or checking `$_POST` vars are set, so you'll need to do those little things yourself, but it looks like a decent code base to build on top of ... :)