# How can I display a list of only categories which are marked as 'featured' in the backend?

Tags: plugins, categories, taxonomy

I am trying to find a way to mark certain categories in the backend with some sort of 'featured' flag. I would then retrieve those selected categories and display them on a page.

I couldn't find any featured category plugin which does this; I'm wondering if there is a simple way to do this in WP core.

Note: I don't want featured category index pages, widgets, category images, etc. I simply want to be able to check a box (or similar) next to certain categories, so they are marked as special. Then I need to create a query to retrieve only those.

Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: The only proper way I can think of is to assign a custom field to categories and then filter them based on that. Take a look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8747/94498) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Register a [taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

I usually call it something like "Promotions." (this allows for more to be added easily in the future) From there, create the term "featured."

In your template, uses `wp_query` to display your featured articles, [taxonomy parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)