# Update custom category fields front-end

Tags: categories, custom-field, front-end, terms

**Been using this answer -->> ([link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/6599/7990))** to create some custom fields in my categories
and it works great ! my only problem is that i have a frontend form that allows
creating new categories with an unrelated form and i would like to insert
values for my custom fields as well as each category pre-defined fields

i am currently adding the built in fields aka category name, slug & description
using wp_insert_term using this small check & insert script

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  {
    $clientName = $_POST["clientName"];
    $term_id = $_POST["clientName"];
    $clientKeywords = $_POST["clientKeywords"];
    $clientSlug = $_POST["clientSlug"];
    $parent = '';

    $errorType = 'Category "'. $clientName .'" Added!';

        wp_insert_term($clientName, 'category', array(
        'description'=>$clientKeywords,
        'slug'=>sanitize_title($clientSlug),
        'parent'=>$parent
    )); 
}
```

.
**Again.. inserting the custom fields values from the backend using the 
code i have found in the answer i have linked from at the beginning of 
my question works very well but i have tried a lot of ways to make it 
work from the front-end / integrate it with wp_insert_term and have 
not succeeded so far.**

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function `wp_insert_term` returns the newly created term id (or WP_Error on error), so once your create your term you need to store it's ID and then you can save the "extra fields" using `get_option`, `update_option` something like:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")  {
    $clientName = $_POST["clientName"];
    $term_id = $_POST["clientName"];
    $clientKeywords = $_POST["clientKeywords"];
    $clientSlug = $_POST["clientSlug"];
    $parent = '';

    $errorType = 'Category "'. $clientName .'" Added!';

    $term_id = wp_insert_term($clientName, 'category', array(
        'description'=>$clientKeywords,
        'slug'=>sanitize_title($clientSlug),
        'parent'=>$parent
    )); 
    if (!is_wp_error($term_id)){
        //save here
        $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
        $tag_extra_fields[$term_id]['field'] = strip_tags($_POST['field']);
        $tag_extra_fields[$term_id]['field2'] = strip_tags($_POST['field2']);
        update_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS, $tag_extra_fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bainternet - as useall you deliver an easy to understand working solution ;)