# List the authors that have written posts in a category

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

How can I list the authors of posts in a category in WordPress?

On my blog have three authors and I want to list who written the posts in a category. For example:

```
CAT NAME: INTERNET     AUTHOR: JOHN, DOE, ALEX
CAT NAME: TECH         AUTHOR: JOHN
CAT NAME: CODE         AUTHOR: ALEX
```

Comment: On second thought: Are you asking about authors of a category or authors who have posted in the category?

Comment: Hi Can, welcome to WPSE! You don't need to specify WordPress in the title nor the content, we are here to deal exclusively with WP ;)  :::: Maybe you can add custom fields to the category: [in-house solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/6549/12615) or [plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

Comment: I think this is a poorly written question. You want to be able to list the authors who have written posts in particular categories, correct?

Comment: Exactly, i think, i was poorly write my question. I want to list who written post in a category.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Would you look at this [picture](http://www.screencast.com/t/tb3aQdZY)? How can i do it?

Comment: Pictures don't help. What you want is actually very tricky. I don't know of a function that will do this directly. It is going to be some combination of functions and maybe pure MySQL. I don't know how to do it off the top of my head. I am sure I can do it and I will if I can find the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

CODE:

```
  <?php
    $cat_arr = get_categories(); // Get the list of Categories
    foreach ($cat_arr as $cat_obj) {
        $term_id = $cat_obj->term_id;

        // Print the Name
        ?>
        <br>
        CAT NAME: <?php echo $cat_obj->name ?>, AUTHOR: 
        <?php
        // Get all Posts of that Category
        $posts = get_posts(array('category'=>$term_id));

        $authors_arr = array();
        foreach ($posts as $post_obj) {
            $author_id = $post_obj->post_author;

                // In depends on where you put this code, the include of the file is required
            if (!function_exists('get_userdata')) {
                include '<your WP folder>/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
            }

            $user_obj = get_userdata($author_id);
                // Only Add the author is isn't already added, to avoid printed twice
            if (!in_array($user_obj->user_login, $authors_arr)) {
                $authors_arr[] = $user_obj->user_login; // Instead of user_login you can use any Database field of the "Users" table
            }
        }
        echo implode(', ', $authors_arr) . '<br>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: This is an acceptable way if you also use other elements of the original post objects, such as the posts titles and descriptions. If you don't need these, it's overkill and will severely slow down the site depending on the amount of posts (or categories if you even do this several times on a page). In his answer to a duplicate question @PieterGoosen showed how to avoid this problem: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/231588/148976

Answer (score 1):

WordPress Categories don't have authors in the traditional sense of the term.  You should read up on the [WordPress Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and also look through your wp_terms, wp_term_taxonomy and wp_term_relationships tables to see how WordPress organizes and uses that data.

Comment: Would you look at this [picture](http://www.screencast.com/t/tb3aQdZY)? How can i do it?