# How can i call from custom fields to the category editor?

Tags: plugin-development, categories, custom-field, functions

I [found](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6549/any-examples-of-adding-custom-fields-to-the-category-editor?answertab=active#tab-top) this code for custom field add category editor.

I added custom field to the Category.

e.g. My field name is Hastag and i have a Sport category. And i want to call display Sport's custom field(I want to call current category custom field). How can i do this?

CODE:

```
// the option name
define('MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS', 'my_category_fields_option');

// your fields (the form)
add_filter('edit_category_form', 'my_category_fields');
function my_category_fields($tag) {
    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);

    ?>

<table class="form-table">
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="_ce4-categoryTitle">Full Category Title</label></th>
            <td><input name="_ce4-categoryTitle" id="_ce4-categoryTitle" type="text" size="40" aria-required="false" value="<?php echo $tag_extra_fields[$tag->term_id]['my_title']; ?>" />
            <p class="description">The title is optional but will be used in place of the name on the home page category index.</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    <?php
}


// when the form gets submitted, and the category gets updated (in your case the option will get updated with the values of your custom fields above
add_filter('edited_terms', 'update_my_category_fields');
function update_my_category_fields($term_id) {
  if($_POST['taxonomy'] == 'category'):
    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
    $tag_extra_fields[$term_id]['my_title'] = strip_tags($_POST['_ce4-categoryTitle']);
    update_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS, $tag_extra_fields);
  endif;
}


// when a category is removed
add_filter('deleted_term_taxonomy', 'remove_my_category_fields');
function remove_my_category_fields($term_id) {
  if($_POST['taxonomy'] == 'category'):
    $tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
    unset($tag_extra_fields[$term_id]);
    update_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS, $tag_extra_fields);
  endif;
}
```

And im trying call with this code:

```
<?php
if ( is_category() ) {
    $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
}
 echo $tag_extra_fields[$current_cat->term_id]['my_title']; ?>
```

Comment: I am not sure what is being asked. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I added custom field to the Category. e.g. My field name is Hastag and i have a Sport category. And i want to call display Sport's custom field(I want to call current category custom field). How can i do this?

Comment: Thank you, that helps. Please edit the question with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit your code. And it worked right now. Thank you @s_ha_dum

CODE:

```
if ( is_category() ) {
    $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
}
$tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
if (isset($tag_extra_fields[$current_cat])) {
    echo $tag_extra_fields[$current_cat]['my_title']; //i added this line.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving your extra fields to the `*_options` table so you need to pull them back out of that table. You can copy and cobble together bits of the existing code to do that.

```
if ( is_category() ) {
    $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
}
$tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
// var_dump($tag_extra_fields); // debug
if (isset($tag_extra_fields[$current_cat])) {
    var_dump($tag_extra_fields[$current_cat]);
}
```

Of course, you don't really want `var_dump`. You will want to echo proper markup. I don't know exactly what markup, but that should get you started.

For example, to output the title as an `<h1>` tag:

```
echo '<h1>'.$tag_extra_field['my_title'].'</h1>';
```

This is assuming that I have interpreted the array structure correctly. If that doesn't work uncomment the `var_dump` line and post the output in the question-- code formatting in comments is almost non-existent.

Comment: I edited my code with your answer: '<?php
if ( is_category() ) {
    $current_cat = get_query_var('cat');
}
$tag_extra_fields = get_option(MY_CATEGORY_FIELDS);
// var_dump($tag_extra_fields); // debug
if (isset($tag_extra_fields[$current_cat])) {
    var_dump($tag_extra_fields[$current_cat]);
}
 echo $tag_extra_fields[$tag->term_id]['my_title']; ?>'

Code output : 'array(2) { ["my_title"]=> string(15) "#hastagbusiness" ["my_description"]=> string(0) "" } '

Comment: That looks like it worked.

Comment: I want just this #hastagbusiness but code output: array(1) { [51]=> array(2) { ["my_title"]=> string(15) "#hastagbusiness" ["my_description"]=> string(0) "" } } array(2) { ["my_title"]=> string(15) "#hastagbusiness" ["my_description"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Yes, that is what [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) does and that is why I explained that "... you don't really want var_dump. You will want to echo proper markup." There is an example of that markup in my answer.